# is it possible to set proxy_cache_valid with less than 1s

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

is it possible to create a proxy caching validation less than 1 second on Nginx?
there are any alternatives to do caching less than 1 second (100ms)

I try to add the next line inside /etc/nginx/site-available/default

```
proxy_cache_valid 200 1ms;
```

As a result

```
[emerg] 23477#23477: invalid time value "1ms" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:73
```

Comment: Did you try and fail ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 I have added the scenario

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible at the moment. Per an upstream statement https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1505:

> As of now, cache validity time can only be set with seconds
> granularity, much like in the Cache-Control: max-age= and Expires
> headers.
>
> While currently there are no plans to change this, I think we can
> consider adding milliseconds if there are enough requests for this.
> Likely there will be various implementation problems though, as 32-bit
> signed integer can't hold more than 24 days in milliseconds.

So, please, raise your voice at upstream ticket.